# Data Driven application in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to create simple data driven application in Silverlight with one DataGrid and class. I am not able to display data into Datagrid.

Here is my code,

```
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Item Name"/>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Barode}" Header="Barcode"/>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Price}" Header="Price"/>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Cost}" Header="Cost"/>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Stock}" Header="Stock"/>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Department}" Header="Department"/>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

Here is my class,

```
public ItemDetails()
    {
        _itemDetails = new ObservableCollection<ItemInf> 
        {
            new ItemInf {Barcode = "123456",Name = "12Pk Corona Extra",Price = 16.00, Cost = 15.99, Stock = 23, Department = "Beer"},
            new ItemInf {Barcode = "234567",Name = "6Pk Corona Extra",Price = 7.99, Cost = 5.99, Stock = 29, Department = "Beer"},
        };            
    }
```

Can anyone help me where I am making mistake or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: where are you assigning itemsource for the datagrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you assign the data source / data context for the datagrid to public property on your class ?

e.g.

```
mydatagrid.ItemsSource= ItemsDetailsInstance.itemcollection property
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set  `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` for you datagrid.